# How is quasiconcavity and the sign of cross partial related?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is differentiable.

If $f(x,y)$ is quasiconcave, is the cross partial nonnegative?

Or, if $f(x,y)$ is strictly quasiconcave, is the cross partial strictly positive?

My initial attempt was to start from the definition that includes $min$. But it doesn't work out very well.